# EXCEL убрать из списка дат выходные

Tags: excel, vba

Нужно вывести списком рабочие дни ( С пн-пт)

Сейчас используется формула

```
=ЕСЛИ(B19+A20>$D$2;"";B19+1)
```

Где, Ячейка D2 -  конечная дата,
B19- вчера
А20 - номер дня

В идеале должно быть так. Указали диапазон даты, и ниже заполнился столбец  с рабочими числами

Comment: `j = 0` `For i = StartDate To EndDate`  `If Weekday(i + 1 - StartDate, vbMonday) < 6 Then`  `j = j + 1`   `Cells(j, 1).Value = CDate(i)` `End If` `Next`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*B2* - начальная дата, *D2* - конечная дата. В *B3* и протянуть ниже:

```
=ЕСЛИ(B2<>"";ЕСЛИ(B2+ВЫБОР(ДЕНЬНЕД(B2;2);1;1;1;1;3;2;1)>$D$2;"";B2+ВЫБОР(ДЕНЬНЕД(B2;2);1;1;1;1;3;2;1));"")
```

Из-за того, что нужно проверять верхнюю дату, фрагмент в формуле повторяется два раза.

Вообще, правильно - не мешать в одном диапазоне данные разного формата - даты и текст (а **""** - пустая текстовая строка). Поэтому в формуле можно заменить **""** на нули, а чтобы нулевые значения визуально не мешали:
*Файл-Параметры-Дополнительно-Для листа*, снять галку *показывать нули в ячейках*

'---------------------------

Макросом.

*Akina* показал оптимальный вариант цикла. Соедините его с показанным ниже вариантом обработки (работа в массиве) и получите оптимальный и быстрый код )

```
Sub WorkingDays()
    Dim aDate()
    Dim dS As Date, dF As Date
    Dim i As Date, k As Long
        dS = Range("B2").Value: dF = Range("D2").Value ' граничные даты'
        If dS = dF Then Exit Sub ' выходим, в диапазоне одна дата'

        k = dF - dS + 1: ReDim aDate(1 To k, 1 To 1) ' размерность массива по макс к-ву дат'
        k = 1: aDate(k, 1) = dS

        For i = dS + 1 To dF ' по датам заданного диапазона'
            If Weekday(i, 2) < 6 Then
                k = k + 1: aDate(k, 1) = i ' запись даты в массив'
            Else
                i = i + 7 - Weekday(i, 2) ' перескакиваем через выходные
            End If
        Next i

        Range("B2").Resize(k, 1).Value = aDate ' выгружаем даты на лист'
    End Sub
```

*Alt+F11* - вход в редактор *VBA*. Слева - дерево проекта. Код разместить в общем модуле проекта (если его нет, добавить - *Insert-Module*).